# create table with variable number of columns in sql

Tags: python, sql, scrape

I'm scraping one site. 
And there are several tables that represent attributes of one observation.
I wonder if it is useful to put images in this post because It's Korean alphabet.
I insert explanation image.

[image]

There are many tables. I will reshape those table into one table, which will be one record and many fields.
But I got a problem.
A few tables have variable numbers of columns.
I'd like to store those data in sql.
From what I know, sql table has fixed numbers of fields.
Do you have a solution what I have to search??

Here is the link. http://goodauction.land.naver.com/auction/ca_view.php?product_id=1698750&class1=5&ju_price1=&ju_price2=&bi_price1=&bi_price2=&num1=&num2=&lawsup=0&lesson=0&next_biddate1=&next_biddate2=&state=91&b_count1=0&b_count2=0&b_area1=&b_area2=&special=0&e_area1=&e_area2=&si=11&gu=0&dong=0&apt_no=0&order=&start=0&total_record_val=&detail_search=&detail_class=1&recieveCode=

Those variables in table in this link indicate the winning bid, number of floors in apartment, size of the area, use of floor,  and so on

And Do you recommend some sites to me in which I learn to scrape the table consisting of cells spanning multiple rows and columns using python.

Comment: I suggest rethinking the approach of `I will reshape those table into one table, which will be one record and many fields`.  That's rarely, if ever, a good idea.

Comment: I'd like to analysis this table using regression or something else. so I think I should convert many tables into one table. What is your suggestion?

Comment: It's not clear what purpose your "database" serves, but a single table is almost certainly a bad way of organizing it. You probably either need to look into relational modeling and learn about 1-to-many relationships or you need to learn about dimensional modeling and create some kind of star schema. Another possibility is that a document database (these are NoSQL databases) would be more suited to your usage. The fact you don't know about these techniques makes your question far too broad.

Comment: Thanks~~ If I use star schema and I will get many dimensional tables as far as I understand. I think there is one problem. If a few dimensional tables have variable numbers of fields how can I fix it?? should I make many fields that has null??

Comment: Oh~ maybe I will solve this problem using 1-to-many. Is it right??

Answer (score 0):

If you have a table *appartment*, you need a table *floor* related to *appartment*